# How to find a specific word in HTML using Java?

Tags: java

I am having a bit of some trouble with this. I tried using Regex but Regex does not give me the exact number of matches I need. I know how many matches I am suppose to have.

I am trying to find all occurrences of a specific word on a `.txt` file that is just an `html` page in text.

The problem is, the word I am searching for can be an `id, class, or just in text` on the website so I need to scrape the entire website for the word.

Also, with Regex, if the word was 'car' Regex was matching it with 'racecar', for example.

I looked into https://jsoup.org/ and is that the best way to go.

Just so I am clear, I watch my method to find, in this example, 'dog', twice in this piece of HTML

```
<p id="Dog">The dog went for a walk today.</p>
```

I hope I am clear - this might even be able to be done with Regex but I could have doing it incorrectly. I was using `Pattern` and using my pattern as `\\bwordToBeSearchedFor\\b`

Comment: yes jsoup best way for parse html

Comment: "this might even be able to be done with Regex" [No it can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1898563).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is wrong with regex actually, i.e. pattern like `(?m)(?u)\W(car)\W` and html like `<html>
 <head>
             <title>car</title>
     </head>
     <body>
           <p id="car" class="car">A racecar and just a  car</p>
      </body>
</html>`

Comment: Check it [your self](http://myregexp.com?regex=%5CW(car)%5CW&text=%3Chtml%3E%0A%09%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3Ecar%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20id%3D%22car%22%20class%3D%22car%22%3EA%20racecar%20and%20just%20a%20car%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&flags=)

Comment: If all you want is to count the number of exact matches then using regular expression should be sufficient. But the real problem here is that your question is not very clear, to me it looks like you're asking for us to recommend a tool to use which is considered an off-topic question.

Comment: Yeah that’s true, Joakim. I just want to be able to get exact matches from the entire string but Regex hasn’t been helpful for me.